# What is the best way to create this table layout? (image attached)

Tags: html, css

I want to create an html table that is best supported on all browsers,
and that is w3c compliant. 
The table shall consist 3-4 elements in it:

1. Text in the blue area - the text might be (a) shown as an image (so I can use nicer fonts, and I'll know for sure that all browsers display it the same way), or (b) might be real text (which would load faster), I haven't decided it.
2. Background image - according to the above decision, either (a) one background image that would cover both blue and pink parts, or (b) just the pink area, while the blue area would just use css background, and I'll write the text inside.
3. Text that would be positioned exactly where the yellow area is.
4. An image that would be positioned exactly where the green area is.

[image: example]

Are the following codes for each of the a/b options are good enough?

Option A:

```
<table width="700" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr> 
  <td height="680" style="background-image: url(bgimg.jpg)";>
  <div style="width: 150px; height: 70px; margin-top: 280px; margin-left: 520px; text-align: center; background-color: #FF0;" >
  text
  </div>
  <div style="width: 400px; height:40px; margin-top:242px; margin-left:18px; background-color:#063;">image</div>

  </td>
</tr>
```

Option B:

```
<table width="700" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr> 
  <td width="500" height="680" bgcolor="#C6F3F9">

  <div style="width: 400px; height:40px; margin-top:590px; margin-left:18px; background-color:#063;">image</div>
        </td>

  <td width="200" style="background-image: url(right-cell-bg.jpg)";>
  <div style="width: 150px; height: 70px; margin-top: 80px; margin-left: 20px; text-align: center; background-color: #FF0;" >
  text
  </div></td>
```

for example:

a. Shall I position the yellow and green areas with DIVs?

b. Should I use additional DIVs (maybe for the cells)?

c. Is style-margin is the best way to acheive the positioning?

d. should I define cell widths with html or with style-width?

e. any other comments.

Thanks!

Comment: This looks like tables being used for layout purposes, not for expressing tabular data.

Comment: yeah maybe I used to wrong terminology by "coding", I changed the subject.

Comment: Before you continue you should note that you use tables mostly to display data not to layout your website. If you intend to use this to structure your website you should reconsider your actions.

Comment: can you go into some more detail about this? what are the disadvantages of using a table?

Comment: jayjay, do a search for Semantic HTML

Comment: If you use display:table/table-row/table-cell ... you can then use semantic tags and have them behave together like a <table><tr><td> does , this is okay since IE8. It's in fact in the W3C spec since 1998 !

Answer (score 1):

Don't use tables, use CSS.  Something like this:

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="blue">
        <div id="image">
            Image
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="pink">
        <div id="text">
            Text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: 700px;
    min-height: 680px;
    position: relative;
}
#blue {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    background: #C6F3F9;
    width: 500px;
    min-height: 680px;
}
#blue #image {
    position: absolute;
    left: 18px;
    bottom: 10px;
    background: green;
    width: 400px;
    height: 40px;
}
#pink {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    background: #FAAEAE;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 680px;
}
#pink #text {
    position: absolute;
    left: 25px;
    top: 305px;
    background: yellow;
    width: 150px;
    height: 70px;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mr_mayers/jHT3Z/

Comment: thanks, I would take some time to check this out